Using einsum of Numpy
I am trying to introduce the expression in Python
$$
\left(\partial_q n_b \partial_q n_b \partial_s n_c \partial_s n_c-\partial_q n_b \partial_s n_b \partial_s n_c \partial_q n_c\right)
$$
where
nb = np.array([cos(theta)*sin(B*phi), cos(theta)*cos(B*phi), sin(theta)])

and $\partial_s$ is the gradient in spheric coordinates, using einsum.
I have used
expr = np.einsum('i,i,j,j->', grad_theta, grad_theta, grad_phi, grad_phi) 
       - np.einsum('i,j,i,j->', grad_theta, grad_phi, grad_phi, grad_theta)

what seems correct for me, but I obtained the error:

ValueError: operand has more dimensions than subscripts given in einstein sum, but no '...' ellipsis provided to broadcast the extra dimensions.

I took a look to some post of this webpage about einsum, but I do not understand my mistake.
This is the definition of $n$:
nb = Matrix([sin(theta)*sin(B*phi), sin(theta)*cos(B*phi), cos(theta)])

grad_theta = diff(nb, theta) * (1/r)
grad_phi = diff(nb, phi) * (1/(r*sin(theta)))

so,
grad_theta = Matrix([
[sin(B*phi)*cos(theta)/r],
[cos(theta)*cos(B*phi)/r],
[          -sin(theta)/r]])


Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Here it looks like grad_theta and grad_phi are 2D arrays, hence you need 2 indices in the einsum script.

'i,i,j,j->' takes 4 1d arguments.  What are the dimensions of your arrays?  What do you intend einsum to do with them?  You might want to experiment with the documented examples.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Show working code without ``einsum..Remember einsum` is primarily a generalized matrix multiplication tool.  SO does not display matb expressions nicely.

Hi, thank you, I have just added it

The additions don't answer our questions.

Sorry, I do not understand what you need.

Can you provide 2 matrices, with specific numerical values, that provide the values of grad_theta, grad_phi? When defining this, do not define them in terms of other variables to which we don't have access. Make them self-contained.

grad_theta has 2 dimensions (1,3), and you're only telling einsum what to do with one of the dimensions (it won't infer to drop the "empty" dimension).  try  using grad_theta.squeeze() instead.

Also if Matrix([...]) is an alias for np.matrix - that's been deprecated for so long that I'm surprised any code using it works anymore.  Use np.array
